# unable to add extension

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, extensions, facebook

I was unable to install extension. 
When I went to magento admin system-> magento Connect-> Magento Connect Manager, the page showed "Error 403 - Forbidden
You don't have permission to access the requested resource. Please contact the web site owner for further assistance." Therefore I can not install through magento admin.

Then I tried another way. I downloaded the extension and try to install through fileZilla. In the downloaded folder of extension, there are a fold called app and a file called package. However, when I tried to upload the app folder and package file through fileZilla to public_html, filezilla asked me to rewrite the folder app or not.

I failed to try both two ways. Is there anyone can help me out? 
The extension I am trying to install is facebook pixel and my magento version is 1.9. Please help me out.

Comment: You can see the answer in our FAQ https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/magento-2-modules-list.html

Answer (score 1):

Most extensions are packaged up and only include the folders that contain the extension files. For example, if the extension was:

Dreystone_Seo

It includes the files for the following location:

- app/code/community/Dreystone/Seo/*
- app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/dreystone/seo.xml
- app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/dreystone/seo/*
- app/etc/modules/Dreystone_Seo.xml

When you tried to copy the extension via FTP, you ran a serious risk of completely overriding your app folder. What you really need to do is a merge of all of the files.

See:

https://www.cminds.com/down-to-the-basics-how-to-install-a-magento-extension/

Answer (score 0):

For your problem I can say You have to give write permission `downloader` folder located in your magento root directory.

Magento stores your extension Within that directory and then install from there so you have to give write permission to `downloader` directory

Answer (score 0):

If you have to download the file and do it manually, instead of doing it folder by folder you can use this free script I made to add it in automatically

https://github.com/cameraki/Install-Magento-Extension-From-File